# i am trying to decode a Huffman tree but i am having some problems

Tags: python, algorithm, huffman-code

i have created and encoded a Huffman tree and put it in a binary file but now when i try to decode it i am getting this error:
line 28, in 
Huffman_Decoding(data, tree)
File "/Users/georgesmac/Desktop/python_course/decompress.py", line 12, in Huffman_Decoding
for x in encoded_data:
TypeError: 'node' object is not iterable
the decode code:

```
import pickle
with open("binary.bin", "rb") as file_handle:
    data = pickle.load(file_handle)
    file_handle.seek(0)
    tree = pickle.load(file_handle)

def Huffman_Decoding(encoded_data, huffman_tree):
    tree_head = huffman_tree
    decoded_output = []
    for x in encoded_data:
        if x == '1':
            huffman_tree = huffman_tree.right
        elif x == '0':
            huffman_tree = huffman_tree.left
        try:
            if huffman_tree.left.symbol == None and huffman_tree.right.symbol == None:
                pass
        except AttributeError:
            decoded_output.append(huffman_tree.symbol)
            huffman_tree = tree_head

    string = ''.join([str(item) for item in decoded_output])
    return string


Huffman_Decoding(data, tree)
```

the encode code:

```
import pickle
q = {}
a_file = open("george.txt", 'r')
for line in a_file:
    key, value = line.split()

    q[key] = value


class node:
    def __init__(self, freq, symbol, left=None, right=None):
        self.freq = freq

        self.symbol = symbol

        self.left = left

        self.right = right

        self.huff = ''


def printNodes(node, val=''):
    newVal = val + str(node.huff)
    if(node.left):
        printNodes(node.left, newVal)
    if(node.right):
        printNodes(node.right, newVal)

    if(not node.left and not node.right):
        print(f"{node.symbol} -> {newVal}")


chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

# frequency of characters
freq = [q['a'], q['b'], q['c'], q['d'], q['e'], q['f']]

nodes = []

for x in range(len(chars)):
    nodes.append(node(freq[x], chars[x]))

while len(nodes) > 1:
    nodes = sorted(nodes, key=lambda x: x.freq)

    left = nodes[0]
    right = nodes[1]
    left.huff = 0
    right.huff = 1
    newNode = node(left.freq+right.freq, left.symbol+right.symbol, left, right)
    nodes.remove(left)
    nodes.remove(right)
    nodes.append(newNode)

printNodes(nodes[0])
with open('binary.bin', 'wb') as f:
    b = pickle.dumps(nodes[0])  # bytes representation of your object
    f.write(b)
```

Comment: first you should open with  `rb` flags and `read` only outputs the content of the file

Comment: when i opened it with rb this error happend: "line 15, in Huffman_Decoding
    if huffman_tree.left.symbol == None and huffman_tree.right.symbol == None:
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'left'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): line 25, in <module>
    Huffman_Decoding(data, tree)
  line 18, in Huffman_Decoding
    decoded_output.append(huffman_tree.symbol)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'symbol'

Comment: if it's pickled data. you must unpickle it

Comment: i tried this: with open("binary.bin", "rb") as file_handle:
    data = pickle.load(file_handle)
    tree = pickle.load(file_handle)
but i got this error: data = pickle.load(file_handle)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'node' on <module '__main__' from decompress.py

Comment: please update your question, don't answer in comments

Answer (score 0):

You pickled objects of type `node`. Python to unpickle them into objects needs `node` class. Since you created it with class `node` defined in main module that is where python looks for it.

You should either import the `node` class or define it in decompress.py.

More clean solution would be to create a module specifically for `node` class and in both, pickling and unplickling code import it from there.

Comment: when i imported the class node i got error run out of input

Comment: Could you paste the error?

Comment: line 5, in <module>
    tree = pickle.load(file_handle)
EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: I see, you are reading twice from the same file descriptor. After first `read` file descriptor point at the end of the file. Add `file_handle.seek(0)` in between.

Comment: Or, since you expect `data`, you should read from file with data ;)

Comment: I don't know what to say, from what I understand you don't have any `data` in that file, just node structure. Don't know what you expect.

Comment: I also don't think you should overwrite the question, it makes the answers unusable for anyone else. I think the convention is to add the `Edit` section at the end of the question to make progress apparent to everyone.